# Maintain factory variable on reload

Tags: angularjs, factory

I have two views of a website built in AngularJS, one for a filtered list of posts and one for a specific post. Each has its own controller, and in order to implement a button that could return the user to the filtered list I need to be able to pass the specified category and page to the post-specific controller.

I've implemented this using a factory as follows:

```
app.factory('ListingFactory', function () {
  var listing = {};

  return {
    get: function () {
      return listing;
    },
    set: function (newCategory, newPage) {
      listing.category = newCategory;
      listing.page = newPage;
      return listing;
    }
  }
});
```

which I'm using to pass the category and page into the post-specific controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ListingController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$stateParams', '$modal', 'Listing', 'Seller', 'Comment', 'ListingFactory', function($scope, $rootScope, $window, $location, $anchorScroll, $stateParams, $modal, Listing, Seller, Comment, ListingFactory) {
  Listing.find($stateParams.id, {bypassCache: true}).then(function(data) { 
    $scope.listing = data;
  });

  var listingData = ListingFactory.get();

  $scope.category = listingData.category;
  $scope.page = listingData.page;

  $window.$scope2 = $scope;
}]);
```

The issue is that reloading the post-specific view causes the factory variable `listing` to be reset.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sessionStorage` to store the values updated. This will hold these during the page reload. However, will be disappeared when the page (Browser) closes.

```
app.factory('ListingFactory', function () {
  var listing = {};

  return {
    get: function () {
      return listing;
    },

    set: function (newCategory, newPage) {
      listing.category = newCategory;
      listing.page = newPage;

      sessionStorage["listingData"] = JSON.stringify(listing);

      return listing;
    },

    init : function() {
       var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["listing"]); 
       listing.category = data.category;
       listing.page = data.page;

       return;
    }
  }
});
```